# Duplication of result

Tags: python, loops

Hi everyone so I am new and trying out loops in python please i keep getting my result duplicated why is this?

```
cleanHello = 'you asked about clean hello'
greetings = 'hi'

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = input('user: ')
            for x in userInput:
                if x in greetings:  
                    print(cleanHello)
        except(KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
            break

main()
```

Comment: What is the user input, the expected output, and the actual output you are getting?

Comment: Visualize your code execution - http://www.pythontutor.com/.  If you are using an IDE, now is a good time to learn its debug tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do 
`for x in some_string`, `x` loops over each character in the string.
So if your `userInput` is `"hi"`,
In the first looping, `x` is `"h"` so it is in `"hi"`.
In the second looping, `x` is `"i"` so it is also in `"hi"`.
So it will print two times. If your `greetings` and `userInput` is same string with `n` letters, it will print `n` times.

---

I think you are trying to do this.

```
cleanHello = 'you asked about clean hello'
greetings = ['hi'] # add more greetings if needed

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = input('user: ')
            if userInput in greetings:  
                print(cleanHello)
        except(KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
            break

main()
```

This prints `cleanHello` if userInput is one of greetings.

Comment: You are right, Thanks, I used the for loop because I was thinking If I choose to tokenize the input later it would be able to search through. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in userInput:
    if x in greetings:
        ...
```

You're iterating through each character in your input and checking if that single character is in greetings or "hi".

You might be trying to do this:

```
cleanHello = 'you asked about clean hello' 
greetings = 'hi' 

def main(): 
    while True:
        try: 
            userInput = input('user: ') 
            if greetings in userInput:
                print(cleanHello)
        except(KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit): 
            break 

main()
```

If you type in "say hi", it will check if "hi" is in the text you entered and then print cleanHello.